# Alternative to Using Expression as Variable?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, expression

Forgive me if this question is a repeat, but I'm stuck with a code I've been working on.
I am creating a program for myself to create random teams of people, and I've been trying to find an easy way to make an inserted amount of teams.
The area I am suck on is here:

```
print("How many teams would you like?")
numberteam = input("Number: ")

listnumber = 0

teams = []
while numberteam + 1:
    teams.append(Team(str(listnumber + 1)) = [])
```

I am a fairly new coder, so I'm sure besides the obvious using an expression for a variable there are probably other mistakes, but any suggestions on an easy way to fix this would be great!

Also if I left something out, please just ask!
(By the way I am using python)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your code, but it seems like a combination of `random.shuffle` and list slicing would be your best bet...

Comment: Also, keep in mind that python isn't C.  `while numberteam + 1:` isn't  doing what you expect.  It is adding 1 to `numberteam`, then discards the value.  `numberteam` is not being updated.

Comment: So seth, I was hoping to create new lists, and have their variables be Team1, Team2... etc. until the desired amount of teams was reached. Then, later on, I would take the names of people, randomly shuffle them, and put them into these lists.

Comment: I see, you want a dictionary!

Comment: Oh yes I haven't coded in awhile, I know what I can do to fix that. Im basically just wondering how I would be able to make a new list for every iteration, to create the desired amount of teams.

Comment: @GafRiedS You should be using a data structure that allows you to add "teams", rather than trying to dynamically create variables to store them. Either a list of tuples/lists ; or a Dictionary would be fine.

Comment: Dictionary? I shall look that up! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Is `Team` a function?

Comment: @aIKid They wanted to make a new variable with `Team#`, where `#` is a number.  They were not familiar with python syntax.

Comment: Ah i see. That's why it looks a bit strange. I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I cleaned things up a bit):

```
print("How many teams would you like?")
numberteam = int(input("Number: "))
# Create a dictionary, where each team has an emtpy list
teams = dict([('Team{}'.format(i), []) for i in range(numberteam)])
# The following also works
# teams = {'Team{}'.format(i):[] for i in range(numberteam)}
```

You can then access the teams like this:

```
teams['Team3'] # returns an empty list
```

---

The longhand for the above is

```
print("How many teams would you like?")
numberteam = int(input("Number: "))
teams = {}
for i in range(numberteam):
    teams['Team{}'.format(i)] = []
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! I am a new coder, and haven't quite gotten around to looking into what dictionary does. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if the OP had python2 or python3, so I went with a solution that would work for both.  Although, now that I think about it it looks like python3 based on the `print` syntax and `input`.

Comment: @SethMMorton Check the tags ;)

Comment: @Haidro Haha, I'm really unobservant tonight

Comment: @SethMMortonn I am sorry to bring this back, but I have another question. Now that I have these empty team lists, how do I randomly place people in these lists, according to how many teams the user wants?

Comment: @SethMMorton I have already created lists of each age group I want, determined how many of each group is needed for each team, randomly shuffled them, but now I just want to know how to place them in each Team list.

Comment: @GafRiedS Since this is different from the question originally asked, I recommend that you post a new question.  You will get fresher eyes that way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
import random

persons = ['Adan', 'Boris', 'Carla', 'Dora', 'Ernesto', 'Floridalma', 'Gustavo', 'Hugo', 'Ines', 'Juan']
random.shuffle (persons)

count = int(input('How many teams? '))
teams = [persons[i::count] for i in range(count)]
for idx, team in enumerate(teams):
    print ('Team {}: {}'.format(idx + 1, ', '.join(team)))
```

The content of `person` doesn't need to be strings, it can hold instances of a custom `Person` class or whatever you like.

---

Explanation:

1. Populate a list from which to chose.
2. Shuffle it in place.
3. Prompt the user for the number of teams and convert the input into an integer.
4. Create the teams. `person[i::count]` picks from persons each count-th element starting at index i. Hence if e.g. count is 3, in the first team are the (shuffled) indices 0, 3, 6, etc, in the second team 1, 4, 7, etc, etc.
5. Print it.

---

The general slicing notation is `iterable[start:stop:step]`.

---

Or if you want to use dictionaries, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
teams = {'Team{}'.format(i + 1): persons[i::count] for i in range(count)}
for k, v in teams.items():
    print ('{}: {}'.format(k, ', '.join(v) ) )
```

Comment: I see... it looked like C++'s namespace syntax at first.  I should have read that at a slice.

Comment: Thanks to python's list comprehensions and slicing, you can build your teams by just executing `teams = [persons[i::count] for i in range(count)]`.

Comment: @SethMMorton I added a second version using dictionaries instead of lists.